# How can I center the second row of a gridview?

Tags: java, android, android-gridview

I´m trying to center, stretch, shrink the rows of a gridview but has been impossible. I´m inflating a gridview with 7 imageviews. The gridview shows the imageviews like this:

[imageview][imageview][imageview][imageview] 
[imageview][imageview][imageview]

I need that the gridview looks like this:

[imageview][imageview][imageview][imageview] 
     [imageview][imageview][imageview]

this is my gridview code:

```
    <GridView android:id="@+id/player_tell_grid"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@id/player_tell_message"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp" android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:numColumns="4" android:columnWidth="45dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp" android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth" android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_tell" android:shrinkColumns="*">
    </GridView>
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do is not possible with a single GridView.

Either add a second one (with different padding) or consider a different layout if you have a limited number of items: TableLayout, RelativeLayout maybe?